# Nodejs: disconnected client from the server by socketio

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I trying to use socket.io to send my data in real time form so in order to i create a server :

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const socket = require('socket.io')(http);

socket.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log('connected:', socket.client.id);

    socket.on('start', data => {
        console.log('new message from client:', data);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log(`server listening on port: ${3000}`))
```

On client part i create this script :

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    // socket connected
    socket.emit('start', { my: 'data' });
    setInterval(() => {
        socket.disconnect();
    }, 1000);

});
```

Imagine after that the client connect to server and send data to server want be disconnected from server so i put this command :

```
setInterval(() => {
    socket.disconnect();
}, 1000);
```

When this command execute i got this error:

```
D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client>node client.js
D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\socket.js:136
Socket.prototype.emit = function (ev) {
                                 ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Socket.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\socket.js:136:34)
    at Socket.socket.on (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\client.js:13:12)     
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
    at Socket.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\socket.js:138:10)
    at Socket.socket.on (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\client.js:13:12)     
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
    at Socket.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\socket.js:138:10)
    at Socket.socket.on (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\client.js:13:12)     
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
    at Socket.emit (D:\Projects\NodeJs\SafaProjects\socket\client\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\socket.js:138:10)
```

How can the client disconnected from the server without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `socket.disconnect()` over an over again. Provide a callback function to `socket.emit()` in which you call `socket.disconnect`.

### server

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const socket = require('socket.io')(http);

socket.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log('connected:', socket.client.id);

    socket.on('start', data => {
        console.log('new message from client:', data);
        socket.emit ('messageSuccess', data);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log(`server listening on port: ${3000}`))
```

### client

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    // socket connected
    socket.emit('start', { my: 'data' };

socket.on ('messageSuccess', function (data) {
 socket.disconnect();
});
});
```

Comment: It was my mistake i have to use `setTimeout(() => {
        socket.disconnect();
    },1000);` but still got that error @Tom Marienfeld

Comment: I change my code like you but `function (response)` never called ?@Tom Marienfeld

Comment: Change `my` to `start` on your client

Comment: `socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('start', { my: 'data' }, function (response) {
        socket.disconnect();
        } );`  what is your mean of `Change my to start` ? @Tom Marienfeld

Comment: I was on the wrong path. Callback function wont be called, because the server is not responding anything to the client. I changed my code, have a look at it. Now the server sends a response to the client if the message was sent. If the client gets the message, it disconnects. Should work now.